# How to use angular Hostlistener on load of component

Tags: angular, onload

In my angular app, I am using a directive which formats the number. This directive is used in html like below.

HTML

TYPESCRIPT

```
 @Directive({
  selector: '[numFormatter]',
})
export class FormatterDirective implements OnInit {
  private el: HTMLInputElement;
  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private currencyPipe: NumberPipe
  ) {
    this.el = this.elementRef.nativeElement;
  }
    ngOnInit() {
   this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(this.el.value);
  }

   @HostListener('focus', ['$event.target.value'])
   onFocus(value) {
     this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.parse(value); // opossite of transform
  }

   @HostListener('focusout', ['$event.target.value'])
   onBlur(value) {
     this.el.value = this.currencyPipe.transform(value);
   }
  }
```

The directive works well when we focusout of the field. I want to use this directive when the component loads, so that
  if there is a value inthat inout field, it should get formatted. 
  Not sure I I Should use HostBinding or should we use a different approach.

Comment: Calling it in `ngOnInit` doesn't work?

Comment: @Connors, no it doesn't

Comment: I figurred it out. Basically Oninit would work, I haven't tried it. I get the data only after an event on the screen. So I override the method AfterViewChecked